# Is division by $\sum x_i-\bar{x}$ actually null?

Tags: divisibility, regression

I'm trying to find out what are $\hat{β_1}, \hat{β_2}$

$
\left \{
\begin{array}{c @{=} c}
    \frac{∂S( \hat{β_1}, \hat{β_2})}{∂S \hat{β_1}} =-2\sum(yi − \hat{β_1} − \hat{β_2}xi) = 0, \\
    \frac{∂S( \hat{β_1}, \hat{β_2})}{∂S \hat{β_2}}=-2\sum x_i(yi − \hat{β_1} − \hat{β_2}xi) = 0. \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

- The first equation gives
  $\hat{β_1}+ \hat{β_2}\sum(x_i)^2=\sum y_i$

which gives the estimator of the y-intercept:
$\hat{β_1} = \bar{y} − \hat{β_2}\bar{x}$

- The second equation gives: 
  $\hat{β_1}\sum x_i + \hat{β_2}\sum(x_i)^2=\sum x_iy_i$

replacing $\hat{β_1}$ by the expression we found, we have:
$\frac{\sum x_iy_i - \sum x_i\bar{y}}{\sum x_i^2 - \sum x_i\bar{x}}$

And then I received an hint to conclude:  "*use shrewdly the fact that $\sum x_i-\bar{x}$ to conclude on $\hat{β_2}$*"

I have to found that
$\hat{β_2} =\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})y_i}{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2}$

but I thought we couldn't divide by zero?
Is the division by $\sum x_i-\bar{x}$ actually null, then?

Comment: In the denominator there is $\sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2$ which is $\underline{not}$ the same as $(\sum x_i-\bar{x})^2$ because precedence rules indicate that each term is squared before the summation is performed. Since each term is non-negative and only equal to zero when $x_i=\overline{x}$ there is a vanishingly small probability that the entire sum is identically zero (unless $n=1$ of course, where $n$ is the sample size).

Comment: Thanks, should I change the title of my question then?

Comment: I think it would be clearer that way. Also,the hint to conclude should probably say "use shrewdly the fact that $0 = \sum x_i-\bar{x}$ ...